# No hay respuesta al utilizar "findOne" de mongoose en express

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

alguien que haya trabajado con mongoose y express, me pueda identificar que anda mal acá? cuando ejecuta el test, se queda cargando infinitamente sin encontrar nada.

debuggeando me di cuenta que es en la función de moongose "User.findOne" justo donde se queda tildada.

He tratado de investigar en la documentación y por stackoverflow y aun sigo sin encontrar respuesta.

PD: el usuario existe, yo tiro esa funcion directamente en mongoDB y anda perfectamente

```
const searchUserByUsername = async username => {
await User.findOne({ username : 'usuarioprueba' }, 'username' , function (err, user) {
    if(err) return handleError(err);

    if(user) {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
});

return Promise.resolve(false);
}

test('should return true in searchUserByUsername when entering "usuarioprueba" as username', async () => {
    const existeUsuario = await searchUserByUsername('usuarioprueba');
    expect(existeUsuario).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Porque estas utilizando Promise dentro de la función?

Comment: Uhh, no me habia fijado en eso, igual lo trate de manejar con una variable dentro del searchUserByUsername y sigue dando el mismo problema

Comment: Estás mezclando `callbacks` con Promesas. Por otro lado las `Queries` de Mongoose [**no son promesas**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises). Te recomiendo que si vas a usar Promesas con `async/await` entonces te mantengas apegado a este estilo (no uses callbacks). Porque de lo contrario te ocurrirá lo que dices que sucede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando `await` pero tambien le estás pasando un callback a la función. Deberías optar por un método, usas await para que espere a que se resuelva el resultado y sino, usas el callback para cuando se resuelve la promesa. Pero al tener esos conceptos combinados, se esta generando ese error en el funcionamiento.

Callback:

```
const searchUserByUsername = username => {
  User.findOne({ username }, 'username' , function (err, user) {
      if(err) Promise.reject(false)

      if(user) {
          return Promise.resolve(user)
      }
  })

  return Promise.reject(false)
}

searchUserByUsername('usuarioprueba')
  .then( user => console.log(user) )
  .catch( error => handleError(error) )
```

Async/Await

```
const searchUserByUsername = async username => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username }, 'username');
    return user
  }
  catch(e) {
    return e
  }
}

searchUserByUsername(username)
  .then( user => console.log(user) )
  .then( user => console.log(user) )
```